# Swift - Container view outside of screen

Tags: swift, view, constraints, containers

I assume this is an easy problem but I haven't managed to find a solution and it is driving me nuts!

One of my container views in my view container won't follow the constraints I put up. For some reason it ends outside of the screen. The main view controller is included in another view (PageMenu) for the menu below my navigation bar, but I don't think it's relevant. I have another view with PageMenu and when I tried putting the container view there it was properly displayed.

Any help would be appreciated!

**How it looks during runtime**

[image: How it looks during runtime]

**The constraints settings**

[image: The constraints settings]

Thanks in advance

Comment: are we dealing with the middle view ?

Comment: It's the bottom one, the one selected. The middle one is covering the whole screen but is shown one layer below the selected one.

Comment: upload the screenshots with constraints of top and middle view also.. I think we can figure out something then!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! I had tried disabling all other views in case their constraints were interfering, but they had nothing to do with it.

Apparently the view was 34.0 pixels outside the main view which is the height of my PageMenu menu. Because I am lazy, I fixed it in viewDidLayoutSubviews().

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    self.calendarViewContainer.frame = CGRect(...
                                              y: self.calendarViewContainer.frame.origin.y - 34.0,
                                              ...  
}
```

There might be a better solution included in the PageMenu pod, but because this is the only container affected by it, I'll stick with this solution for now.